# Why does my batch file have a long pause when it switches commands?

Tags: batch-file

We run software that we only have 3 licenses for but more users. They bill us if we go over so we created an excel log file that we check in and out of to know if we go over the 3 limit. I created a batch file that would open the excel file then prompt if there's a license available, if yes, then open the software. There is a long pause, 20 to 30 seconds, before it prompts if there's a licences available. It has to be because of the way the Yes/No dialog is done but I don't know much about this stuff. I Frankenstien'd this from thing I found online. Can somebody show me a faster way. Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
call "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE" "M:\RAM\RAM License Log\MultiFamily.xlsm"

:choice

echo wscript.quit MsgBox ("Is there a RAM license available?", 4, "RAM License Log") > yesno.vbs

wscript //nologo yesno.vbs

set value=%errorlevel%

del yesno.vbs

if "%value%"=="6" goto :RAM

if "%value%"=="7" goto :END

goto :choice

:RAM

call "C:\Program Files\Bentley\Engineering\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition V8\Concept.exe"

cls

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" /high "M:\RAM\RAM License Log\MultiFamily.xlsm"

goto :END

:END

exit
```

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: It is alot of information Windows has to run through, there are also other processes in your computer's memory functioning. It may take a couple of seconds just to load Excel itself. Next time you run the batch file, open Task Manager first and have a look.

Comment: So you still rely on the end-user selecting the correct option then. I would go about it another way and have lock or check-in files created in a UNC path i.e. `\\server\share\folder` and then create text files such as `<computername>_<username>.lck` and then have a PowerShell script or batch script that executes PS do some checking and if there's already 3, pop up the PC names and usernames with it in use and then not allow it to be executed, otherwise create a file, and then execute the new instance. You can use `Start-Process` with `-wait` and once closed, have it delete it's file.

Comment: @vssher, the delay comes after Excel closes.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT, I know just enough to take an existing batch file and change the program it opens. What you suggest sounds great but I don't have the knowledge to write scripts

Comment: Oh.... this is part of the custom process you are building to track, etc. I say do the tracking with files *i.e. `<computername>_<username>.lck`* and just keep files this way and have them them delete themselves when the exe is exited. You can also pop up a message showing the current workstation and usernames that have it in-use. I would try to not use macro and Excel for this and keep it simple with simple batch perhaps. If you get something basic put together and have trouble in your journey, each trouble you have is another potential question you can ask separately post wise too.

Comment: Can you explain how you want the process to work and what you need to accomplish ultimately? Track every instance launched forever, disallow more than 3 concurrent instances of the exe being run at a time, have the user say whether or not it is safe to open a new one based on what they see from a list, etc....

Comment: We don't need to track every instance. Does need to disallow more than 3 users. And showing a list of current users would be helpful

Comment: @spykat You still there and checking this, you still need some help with this? Now that you clarified, I have an idea but tag my back by putting `@PimpJuiceIT` so I'm notified of your reply.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, yes I'm still here. I'm so swamped with work I don't have time to worry about this now